# Can I directly Inject ILogger without LoggerFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ilogger, iloggerfactory

From the IoC perspective, we should be able to easily setup and choose the implementation of a interface.

If I create custom implementation of `ILogger`, can I directly injected it to controller without the `ILoggerFactory-ILoggerProvider-ILogger` structure?

In this way I can have less setting overhead and more control on the Logger. For example, I can cast and access the `CustomProperty`. In contrast, the logger created by `ILoggerFactory-ILoggerProvider-ILogger` chain will maintain a collection of `ILogger`s and I can not access my `CustomLogger` any more.

The code will look like below. Is this a feasible solution?

Define CustomLogger

```
public class CustomLogger : ILogger
{
   public CustomPropertyType CustomProperty;

   public CustomLogger(){...}
   public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state){...}
   public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel){...}

   public void Log<TState>(
            LogLevel logLevel,
            EventId eventId,
            TState state,
            Exception exception,
            Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
   {
      // Use some info from CustomProperty in while sending the log
   }
}
```

Setup the Dependency Injection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ILogger, CustomLogger>();
    //Other logic
}
```

Access the `ILogger` with `CustomLogger` implementation

```
public ExampleController(ILogger logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    this.customProperty = (CustomLogger)logger.CustomProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a provider. You can add this in the `Startup` class of your .NET Core application. Such code shall look like this:

```
loggerFactory.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider(new CustomLoggerConfiguration()));
```

[Here](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html) is an explanation of such usage. And [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/logging/index/samples/3.x/CustomLogger/Startup.cs#L31) is an example.

Comment: Is LoggerProvider really needed? From the IoC point of view, we can also just do `services.AddScoped<ILogger, CustomLogger>()` right? Or it's not recommended usage?

Comment: Could work too but providers are the default way as becomes clear from the Microsoft documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-providers